# Javascript keydown-event won't fire on paragraph

Tags: javascript, keydown

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Snake!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="lol"></p>
    <p id="change"></p>
    <script>
        var tableau = new Array(21);

        var direction = [0, 0];

        var word = "MERCI";
        var indice = 1;
        var candy = new Array(2);

        candy[0] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19) + 1;
        candy[1] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19) + 1;

        var snake = [
            [8, 8]
        ];

        function full_array() {
            for (var x = 0; x < 21; x++)
                tableau[x] = new Array(20);

        }

        full_array();

        function full_tab() {

            for (var x = 0; x < 20; x++)
                tableau[0][x] = 1;
            for (var y = 1; y < 20; y++) {
                tableau[y][0] = 1;
                for (var x = 1; x < 20; x++) {
                    tableau[y][x] = '*';
                }
                tableau[y][20] = 1;
            }
            for (var x = 0; x < 20; x++)
                tableau[20][x] = 1;


            for (var i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
                tableau[snake[i][0]][snake[i][1]] = word[(i + word.length) % word.length];
            }

            tableau[candy[0]][candy[1]] = word[indice];
        }

        function aff_tab() {
            var tab = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++)
                tab = tab + tableau[i].toString() + "<br/>";
            document.getElementById("lol").innerHTML = tab;
        }

        document.getElementById("change").innerHTML;


        function move_snake() {

            var sx, sy;
            var sav = [snake[snake.length - 1][0], snake[snake.length - 1][1]];
            for (var i = snake.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                sx = snake[i - 1][1];
                sy = snake[i - 1][0];
                snake[i][0] = sy;
                snake[i][1] = sx;
            }

            snake[0][0] += direction[0];
            snake[0][1] += direction[1];
            if (tableau[snake[0][0]][snake[0][1]] == 1) {
                restart_game();
            }

            full_tab();
            aff_tab();
            if (snake[0][0] == candy[0] && snake[0][1] == candy[1]) {

                add_candy();
                indice++;
                snake.push(sav);
                if (indice == word.length)
                    indice = 0;
            }

        }

        function restart_game() {
            clearInterval(timerID);
            snake = [
                [8, 8]
            ];
            direction = [0, 0];
            indice = 1;
            add_candy();
            full_tab();
            timerID = setInterval(function() {
                move_snake();
            }, 300);
        }

        function add_candy() {
            candy[0] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19) + 1;
            candy[1] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19) + 1;
        }

        var timerID = setInterval(function() {
            move_snake();
        }, 300);

        var game = document.getElementById('lol');
        game.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

                if (e.keyCode == 37)
                    direction = [0, -1];
                if (e.keyCode == 38)
                    direction = [-1, 0];
                if (e.keyCode == 39)
                    direction = [0, 1];
                if (e.keyCode == 40)
                    direction = [1, 0];

            }, false

        );
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to add a keypress event to a paragraph. But it doesnt work. So i would like to know if its possible.
Here is an exemple:

```
var game = document.getElementById("mybalise");
game.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){...}, false);
```

It works when I do:

```
document.addEventListener(...);
```

But its doing it on all the document I guess.
If you need more codes let me know.If you need more codes let me know.If you need more codes let me know.If you need more codes let me know.If you need more codes let me know.
Thanks

Comment: use `game.onkeydown=function(){}`

Comment: We need more codes. We need more codes. We need more codes. We need more codes. We need more codes. We need more codes. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Displaying all relevant source code is the key to receiving a solid/good answer. Can you create a working demo for us to use, this will give people a starting point on finding the problem. Have you checked your browsers console for any errors?

Comment: Codes is not the plural of code, I mistake is alright, but not if you keep repeating the same mistaken, see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20455/is-it-wrong-to-use-the-word-codes-in-a-programming-context

Comment: @Danielson Codes is definitely the plural of code. "Could you hand me the launch codes". However, as the article says, no when used in a context of programming, *flies away*.

Comment: For future reference, you're trying to add an *event callback* not an event.

Comment: lol stack didn't want to accept my post so i copy the last sentence ;). It's not very legal here but i'm kind of a renegate -_-.
Sorry for the mistake, I'm french haha not really an excuse ;). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suggest to use an element more suitable than a paragraph element for your game. `DIV` is more suitable for this.

Answer (score 5):

For the `keydown` to work: add `tabindex="1"` and click it first to receive focus. Else it will only register the document, since that has the focus.

```
game.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){...}, false);
```

This code is absolutely perfect. Click on the changed element with your mouse and start typing.

> keydown works on all HTML elements, EXCEPT: `<base>, <bdo>, <br>, <head>, <html>, <iframe>, <meta>, <param>, <script>, <style>, and <title>`

However, it seems that elements like `span`, `b`, `p` don't receive a proper focus for the keydown-event to fire. You can circumvent this by giving the element a [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/tabIndex) (which means it can be selected with tab). In the example below I've demonstrated this.

```js
document.getElementById("sample").addEventListener("keydown", function(e){e.preventDefault(); alert(e.type)}, false);
```

```css
#sample {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p tabindex="1" id="sample">
  Sample (click me and type)
  </p>
```

Also:
You speak of `keypress` and use `keydown` in your code. Remember that they are totally different events.

Comment: Thank it works ;). Where did you get the informations about the elements ?

Comment: The internet, I browsed Stack and used some Google-fu to find the definitive solution.

Comment: Ha no it doesn't works. Because if i press to many times the down button ,the page is scrowlling down and i want it to be fixe. Thanks

Comment: @user3549047 then put `e.preventDefault()` at the end of your event handler. That should... prevent the... default behaviour of scrolling down :)

Comment: @Amine, that is of course the solution to that problem. Updated the sample.

Comment: ha yes sorry I though that by having the focus to my <p> will solve the problem.